# Logstash configtest

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I ran service logstash configtest but error given was:

> logstash: unrecognized service

I was able to run logstash service individually but not with "configtest". In etc/logstash/conf.d/ I created logstash.conf file where consist of code as present below:-

Additional info:-

```
service logstash status
● logstash.service - logstash
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-12-26 12:40:58 PST; 6s ago
 Main PID: 3512 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/logstash.service
           └─3512 /usr/bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX...

Dec 26 12:40:58 Mr systemd[1]: Started logstash.
```

Service while running with configtest:-

```
root@Mr:/# service logstash configtest
logstash: unrecognized service
```

I am running this on debian8 machine, hope i will get a good solution from you guys.

```
# This input block will listen on port 10514 for logs to come in.
# host should be an IP on the Logstash server.
# codec => "json" indicates that we expect the lines we're receiving to be in JSON format
# type => "rsyslog" is an optional identifier to help identify messaging streams in the pipeline.

input {
  udp {
    host => "logstash_private_ip"
    port => 10514
    codec => "json"
    type => "rsyslog"
  }
}

# This is an empty filter block.  You can later add other filters here to further process
# your log lines

filter { }

# This output block will send all events of type "rsyslog" to Elasticsearch at the configured
# host and port into daily indices of the pattern, "rsyslog-YYYY.MM.DD"

output {
  if [type] == "rsyslog" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "elasticsearch_private_ip:9200" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 61):

for old logstash

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash --configtest -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/
```

Later, it became installed in /usr/share/logstash so try either

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --configtest -f <the config file/folder>
```

Or if running version 5.1+ use `--config.test_and_exit`

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --config.test_and_exit -f <the config file/folder>
```

Comment: -bash: /usr/share/logstash: is a directory. I think you meant "/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash"

Comment: also there is no --configtest in version 5 of logstash. now it's: "   -t, --config.test_and_exit    Check configuration for valid syntax and then exit."

Comment: I am using logstash 6.0 with pipelines. How can i do a config test of the different pipelines? --config.test_and_exit -f <the config file/folder>  ignore the pipelines.yml file completely.

Comment: hi @cybervedaa, are you using -f once or multiple times as it ignores multiple declarations of settings folder. Also, check with debug flag on with --log.level=debug - to get more details.

Comment: You can test pipelines by replacing `-f ...` with `--path.settings /etc/logstash` in this solution @cybervedaa

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and it helped me a lot:

If you are running Logstash version 5, the following command to test the configuration will give you an error:

```
sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --configtest -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/
```

The right command to test it is:

```
sudo -u logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash -t
```

I'm running ELK + filebeat since an Ubuntu Server 16.04 and my result was:
Sending Logstash's logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
Configuration OK

Sources:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash.html; https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6161

Answer (score 9):

for logstash 5.1 its

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --config.test_and_exit -f logstash.yml
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the official `logstash` Docker image to validate a local file:

```
docker run -it -v /etc/logstash:/etc/logstash logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -t -f /etc/logstash/logstash.conf
```

This assumes your config file is locally in `/etc/logstash`, then mounts that folder into the container, under the same path. Then the binary can find the config file inside the container.

There might be a better way to run that command, this worked for me.

Comment: this worked for me but had to change it up for Mac ```docker run -it -v $PWD:/lsconfigs logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -t -f /lsconfigs/logstash.conf``` NOTE: make sure logstash.config is in the root directory you're running the docker command from

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your configs with a docker container logstash 6.x

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/etc/logstash/conf.d --entrypoint "bin/logstash" logstash "--config.test_and_exit"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this on CentOS version 7:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash configtest /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf
```

Comment: /usr/share/logstash/bin  look at this directory,if you install by rpm package

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 7, you can also use the following command:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/
--config.test_and_exit /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
```

Comment: This is logstash version 6.5.1 which was setup using Ansible ELK

Comment: ./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/fileb..conf --config.test_and_exit